# In Gatling, how to iterate json array in .check to validate all values

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

Sample Json Response is

```
{
    "data": {
        "types": [
            {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "body": {
                            "id": 123
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "body": {
                            "id": 456
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "body": {
                            "id": 456
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "body": {
                            "id": 123
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to validate that all id's are 123, if values are other than 123 Gatling test should fail.

I have tried below code it's failing in assertion but gatling report is showing passed. As I guess assert is a juint assert and not gatling assert.

```
val testSC1 = scenario("Sample-test")

     .exec(http("Test-Post")
      .post("dataservice/v1/test")
      .header("Authorization", getToken)
      .body(StringBody(getPayload))
      .asJSON
      .check(jsonPath("$.data.types[*].attributes[*].body.id").findAll.saveAs("getAllId"))
    ).
    exec
    { session =>
        //println(session("getAllId").as[String])
        val iDs = session("getAllId").as[Seq[String]]
        for (getEachId <- iDs)
        {

          assert(getEachId.equals("123"),"Actual:  "+getEachId+"Expected : 123")
        }
        session
    }
```

How do I iterate values in .check method
$.data.types[*].attributes[*].body.id ?

Or any other better solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
jsonPath("$.data.types[*].attributes[*].body.id").findAll.is(Seq("expectedValue1", "expectedValue2", "expectedValue3"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I have another problem that my expected value is constant eg."123" but they are many around 1000+   so how do I add it in Seq("123", "123", "123",.... "123"))

Comment: Create a method that builds this sequence. Then, such in depth validation looks like a functional test, not a load test.

Comment: @shrusthip in your case you can use method `fill`. It will populate your Seq with value N times.
`Seq.fill(1000)("123")`