# Gatling check every value in array

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath, jmespath

I am writing gatling tests and using JSONPath `$..parentId`.
I am getting the response:

```json
[
  "102044",
  "102044",
  "102044"
]
```

I want to check that every value is equal to `102044`. The amount of values can change.
By now I'm checking only random one:

```scala
@Then("then is successful")
override def thenStep(): Seq[HttpCheck] = {
    var checks = List[HttpCheck]()
    checks ::= status.is(session => 200)

    checks ::= jsonPath("$..totalElements").ofType[Int].gt(8)
    checks ::= jsonPath("$..totalElements").ofType[Int].lt(15)
    checks ::= jsonPath("$.data[*].parentId").findRandom.is("102044")
    
    checks
}
```

I tried to save the amount of values and the do something with it, like this:

```scala
checks ::= jsonPath("$..totalElements").ofType[Int].saveAs("all")
checks ::= jsonPath("$.data[*].parentId").findAll.is(Seq.fill(s"$all")("102044"))
```

But this is not working.

Is there a simple solution?
This question is similar to: [In Gatling, how to iterate json array in .check to validate all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67787222/in-gatling-how-to-iterate-json-array-in-check-to-validate-all-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be able to do, using JMESPath is:

```
totalElements
```

To find the `totalElements` property of your JSON.

And

```
length(data[?parentId != '102044'])
```

To find if there are elements where the `parentId` is not `102044`.

So, your assertions end up being be:

```scala
checks ::= jmesPath("totalElements").ofInt().gt(8)
checks ::= jmesPath("totalElements").ofInt().lt(15)
checks ::= jmesPath("length(data[?parentId != '102044'])").ofInt().is(0)
```

---

All this is based on the assumption that your input looks something like what you provided in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70954206/2123530):

```json
{
  "pageable": {
    "currentPage": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "last": true,
    "first": true
  },
  "sort": {
    "orders": [],
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true,
    "empty": true
  },
  "totalElements": 6,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "roleName": "test1",
      "userCount": 5,
      "parentId": "102044"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "roleName": "test2",
      "userCount": 5,
      "parentId": "102045"
    }
  ]
}
```